# .htaccess rewrite rule for a pattern where the URL contains brackets

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, brackets

I have a mod_rewrite rule in place for a clean URL application, however the client is insisting on having brackets in their product name - which ends up in the URL.

Currently using;

```
RewriteRule ^search/([.,'A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([.,'A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /online/product_information.csn?thisCat=$1&thisProd=$2 [QSA,L]
```

There's probably something more concise that can be used but the above does work until those () appear.

Have tried escaping the brackets within the pattern but nope, doesn't work;

```
RewriteRule ^search/([.,'A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([.,'A-Za-z0-9_-\(\)]+)$ /online/product_information.csn?thisCat=$1&thisProd=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Also tried without escaping but that resulted in an "Internal Server Error";

```
RewriteRule ^search/([.,'A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([.,'A-Za-z0-9_-()]+)$ /online/product_information.csn?thisCat=$1&thisProd=$2 [QSA,L]
```

The final URL would be of the form;
http://gouda2019.cohesion.co.nz/search/Smallgoods_--_Fish/Salmon_Krokets_(10)

All help appreciated with my thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be no need to escape the brackets inside a character class. _“Also tried without escaping but that drove the server nuts as expected.”_ - please give us a _proper_ problem description of what happened then, because descriptions like that … well, they drive _us_ nuts :-)

Comment: Hi. Fair enough - sorry about that. Result was  'Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the error log